# Insert into statement with file path

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio

```
string SqlStr = string.Format("insert into O_Tracker " +
           "(order_id,client_name,job_name,note_,s_date,e_date,paid,pickup_status,sub_orders) values " +
           "({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')"      
           ,s.Order_Id, s.Client_Name, s.Job_Name, s.Note, s.Start_Date,
           s.End_Date, s.Paid, s.Ready2Pickup, subOrdersPath);
```

I keep getting this error from the debugger:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

I just can't figure it out what's wrong in here.
thanks for your help in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I've changed the code to a format with parameters and got "mismatch criteria expression access" error.

`string SqlStr ="insert into O_Tracker " +
"(order_id,client_name,job_name,note_,s_date,e_date,paid,pickup_status,sub_orders) values(@order_id,@client_name,@job_name,@note_,@s_date,@e_date,@paid,@pickup_status,@sub_orders)";`

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_id", s.Order_Id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_name", s.Client_Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", s.Job_Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note_", s.Note);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_date", s.Start_Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_date", s.End_Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", s.Paid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pickup_status", s.Ready2Pickup);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_orders", subOrdersPath);

        try
        {             
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandText = SqlStr; 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {              
            cnn.Close();
        }
```

**Summary**

Had a problem to add to a specific table field a file path.
the guys here noticed that my code is vulnerable to SQL injection so i've done as their suggested and fixed my code.

another problem occurred after that and simply fixed it because the date field were not match.

Thanks all for you help! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `SqlStr` when the exception occurs?

Comment: @mjwills 
`"insert into O_Tracker (order_id,client_name,job_name,note_,s_date,e_date,paid,pickup_status,sub_orders) values (1001,'Example','gssgsgsgsgs','אין הערות','19/02/2018 12:21:36','19/02/2018 12:21:36','לא','לא','C:\\Users\\SuperUser\\Dropbox\\My Project\\My Project\\bin\\Debug\\\\Orders\\1001gssgsgsgsgs.txt')"`

Comment: What type is `s.Ready2Pickup` and why is it's value empty?

Comment: Use parameters in your SqlCommand. You shouldn't send formatted strings like this.

Comment: @MongZhu its a typo of mixing hebrew and english in here. the empty one contains the לא after the 12:21:36. in the debugger everything looks fine.

when i change subOrdersPath to just "sample text" it works.

Comment: @SteveHarris i send it to a method that send it like a regular sql query. can you explain me what's wrong with it?

Comment: You should really lookup how to use Sql Parameters, this code is not safe. For help with your query, copy paste the 'SqlStr' and show us what it's like.

Comment: What happens when subOrdersPath = "'); DROP TABLE O_Tracker--"? Sql injection just killed your database!

Comment: @Carra i've already showed in the past comments

Comment: how comes that you have an non existing folder in here: `Debug\\\\Orders` ? what happens if you remove the unnecessary backslash by hand in the debugger?

Comment: @MongZhu the Orders folder exist. and if i remove the unnecessary backslashes nothing changed

Comment: @SteveHarris I've learned my lesson. thank you for showing me this and improved me :)

Comment: by the way, if you are in control of the database structure, consider using an appropriate type (Date, DateTime) instead of sting for `s_date` , `e_date` and other columns storing dates

Comment: and using parameters, among other advantages, will let you easlily handle a client name such "O'Connor" (no need to escape ' if you use parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your string `')'` is seen as a separate string:

```
1001gssgsgsgsgs.txt')'
```

That being said, as has been said in the comments, you must use SqlParameters. Both to prevent Sql Injection and to delimit your strings. Something like this:

```cs
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand('insert into ... values (..., @sub_order)', connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@sub_order", yourSubOrderString);
```

Comment: can you please explain me how i write the insert into query in this method?

`'insert into MyTable (... table fields) values (...,@sub_orders)'`
or
`'insert into My table values (...,@sub_orders)'`

Comment: the table fields are optional but it's good practice to include them, that way if the order of your db fields changes for some reason it still works.